# Shopify Order Image Upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, shopify

I have researched but couldn’t find a robust solution to let customers upload images with a Shopify order (say for personalisation). I want to upload the images to a s3 bucket.

Any help to point me in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Depends on where you are providing the upload option.

Comment: @HymnZ I want the customer to have the option to upload a picture and checkout. So want the upload capability on the product page (storefront).

Comment: Do you want to implement this only on the client side (i.e. javascript) or do you want to have a backend component? Also, do you want your S3 bucket publicly writeable or not?

Comment: @Andre.IDK fronted implementation would suffice. As I can create a separate workflow outside Shopify to deal with the images. I guess I will have to make the S3 publicly writable (unless I can create bucket policy to deal with my domain)

Comment: Your problem is, before checkout, no order exists, so you have nothing to tie the upload to the product and the customer. If you pre-warm the cart, you can try and extract the cart token from the Shopify cookies. If you enforce a customer being logged in, you can tie an upload to the customer if you can find their ID. Tying the upload to an order is tricky in that you will need to quickly react to the order via a webhook in an App, and then try and find the matching upload, to tie it to the order. Not easy anyway. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidLazar great answer. Looks a lot of work plus lot of places where it could go wrong. Is upload facility easy to implement within Shopify? Would be grateful if you could kindly share some resources 

Comment: Sorry, I have never bothered with this pattern. For now, Shopify supports the upload of a customer image per product via their built-in line item properties, so I go with that 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

For a fully frontend solution you should look into Javascript AWS SDK which exposes a nice [S3 interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html).

While you could leave your bucket publicly writeable, I would advice against it for a number of reasons one of them being that anyone could upload anything on it and you'd be responsible and will be billed for it.

There are a few ways in which you can [handle authentication in a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html) that would allow you to avoid having your S3 bucket completely open. At the very least you should look into [CORS configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) (as you also suggested in your own comment).

Once you have decided how to handle authentication you have a few options to upload objects on S3: [simple upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadInSingleOp.html), [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) and [pre-signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Looking for how to achieve that in Shopify restraints.